# Vim create list of files different from master

Tags: git, vim, workflow, pull-request, vim-fugitive

I'm looking for a way to set up Vim so that I can create a list of all the files on the current branch that are different to master(or any other branch of choice).

I already use [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) for git diffing at file level. I would like a way to create a list of all the files that have changed so I can go through them and then use vim-fugitive to review.

This is to help when working on branches other devs have been working on and receiving pull requests. My intention is that I would  fetch and checkout the branch run a command and all the files that have differences to master will go into a quickfix window (or even into my buffers). I could then go through the list of files to review.

Comment: `:h fugitive-:Gstatus`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with a way to do this myself.

Using vim-fugitive and another plugin [vim-merginal](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-merginal)

vim merginal `:Merginal` will display a pane with a list of branches. `gd` on a selected branch gives a list of files that are different. I can then go into the files using `:Gdiff` to view the indivdual changes.

Comment: I've been using Merginal for a while and I still didn't think this would be supported out of the box - cheers.